# Redux alternative for React component interaction for SPFx 1.4 and React 15 - No Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, spfx

As you know, so far even to date, SPFx 1.4 is the supported version for latest onPrem SharePoint (2019). That unfortunately comes only with React 15 which does not support hooks(hooks make life easy for react state and using redux).

We just require to make several react class components talk to each other (like submit button to disable all other components during aync call and enable spinner wheel in meantime as one example scenario).

The forms are too many. Passing call back function from each component to other is definitely not scalable solution.

Upgrading existing React to 16 breaks the SharePoint workbench so our testing is not possible so that route is also not possible.

we considered Formik, but that seems to be only usable for simple type of input controls, while we are using fancy Fluent UI controls and complex poeple pickers.

Need a solution to call components setState function from different components in hierachy without using callbacks. What is simple solution to it? or if know framework can help us here?

Comment: are you using redux currently? As it stands, there's nothing stopping you from using react 15 redux best practices to access global state

Comment: @DerekPollard redux with typescript in spfx is too much verbose of the syntax. it seems to be too much overwhelming for such simple requirements. do you have a simple example of add and using redux in sfpx so we make our components talk to each other

Comment: Are you sure you need global state? Adding redux for one single usecase feels like overkill, you can just use localstate and pass down to the children what they need

Comment: thanks @DerekPollard. we don't need global state or don't know if we do. We have 45 react components. All need to call setState of each rest component setState method. How to achieve that. Also mostly no parent child, all of them child to single root element

Answer (score 1):

it seems we had to add some dummy parent components.

using the state of parent component and passing it down the components as PROPs does serve the same purpose.

change in props also cause the child to re-render and serving the purpose.

Hope this help others in same situation.